# How do I convert an excel file into a nested python dictionary?

Tags: python, excel, dictionary

I have a very specific Excel sheet that looks like this:

[image: Excel Sheet Picture]

I am trying to convert it to a Python dictionary like this:

```
item_map = {
    "1609755": {
        "name": "test 1",
        "price": 125,
        "check_type": "check 1"
    },
    "1609756": {
        "name": "test 2",
        "price": 2500,
        "check_type": "check 2"
    },
    "1609758": {
        "name": "test 3",
        "price": 2400,
        "check_type": "check 3"
    }
}
```

My question is: **How do I convert a excel sheet to a Python dictionary?**

---

So far I tried using the library sheet2dict and also pandas, however in the excel sheet, the `id` is a `key` in the dictionary. As a result, I am quite stumped on how to ensure that the first column is **ALWAYS** set as a key.

```
from sheet2dict import Worksheet
ws = Worksheet()
file_path = 'test.xlsx'

x = ws.xlsx_to_dict(path = file_path)

print(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I do not have the Excel file, I created the DataFrame using your dictionary mentioned in the question i.e, **item_map** likewise:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(item_map).T    #Had to take a Transpose
df.index.name = 'id'
```

You can import your table as a DataFrame using [pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html). Remember to set the index as 'id'.

```
df = pd.read_excel('file_path')
df.index.name = 'id'
```

Then, use this code:

```
item_map = {}

for index, row in list(df.iterrows()):
    item_map[index] = dict(row)

print(item_map)
```

Output:

```
{'1609755': {'name': 'test 1', 'price': 125, 'check_type': 'check 1'},
'1609756': {'name': 'test 2', 'price': 2500, 'check_type': 'check 2'},
'1609758': {'name': 'test 3', 'price': 2400, 'check_type': 'check 3'}}
```

Comment: Thank you, however it seems after importing my table as a dataframe, it automatically specifies the key as 0, 1, 2. How do I specify it as the first column in my Excel file?

Comment: Actually I figured it out: df.set_index('id', inplace=True) will set it so the id is the key.

Comment: Yes, did it work ? I tested my code by recreating your DataFrame.I used the dictionary you have mentioned in your question likewise: df = pd.DataFrame(item_map) .T    and then set the index as:  df.index.name = 'id'

Comment: @ShivamRoy: The initial example only give a flat structure, ie `{0: {'Id': 751, 'Name': 'Test 1', 'Price': 125, 'check_type': 'Check 1'},` Please update the answer with a working solution with nested dicts as OP asked for.

Comment: @IODEV The output would look flat actually, but it is in exactly the same format OP asked for. I tried the code before posting it and it did return me the nested dictionary. I'm sorry if I didn't understand your issue, is it regarding the alignment of the lines ? If you run the code you'll find that the output is in the same nested format as OP asked for.